# $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and Cauchy condensation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a decreasing sequence which converges to 0.

If $2^n a_{2^n}\rightarrow 0$, does it follow that $na_n\rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Let $k:=k_n$ be so that $2^k \leq n <2^{k+1}$. Then

$$a_{2^k} \geq a_n \geq a_{2^{k+1}}$$
and hence

$$ na_{2^k} \geq na_n \geq na_{2^{k+1}} \,.$$

Using $2^k \leq n <2^{k+1}$ we get

$$2^{k+1}a_{2^k}   \geq na_n \geq 2^k a_{2^{k+1}}$$
or

$$2 \cdot \left( 2^{k}a_{2^k} \right)   \geq na_n \geq \frac{2^{k+1} a_{2^{k+1}}}{2}$$

Now when we let $n \to \infty$ we get $k_n \to \infty$ thus

$$2^{k}a_{2^k}\,;\, 2^{k+1} a_{2^{k+1}} \to 0$$

By squeeze theorem  you get your claim.